# Check all {% url %} tags for errors

Tags: django, validation, templates

I'm working on a Django project that is getting bigger and bigger. I'm now reorganizing the `views.py` file, separating it into different modules in the `views` package I've created.

After moving the view functions, I had to find all references to them. Changing `urls.py` was easy. Finding errors in `reverse` calls was also easy - Eclipse marked the ones that had a problem.

However, I can't find a way to go over all `{% url %}` template tags and find the ones that don't reference a view. I can go over them one by one, but any typo will lead to a runtime error.

Is there an automatic way to check `{% url %}` tags for invalid view names?

Comment: Its situation like these where good tests come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are couple of ways to do it.

Most of IDEs have something for `rename` refactoring, PyCharm have this feature to find the usage of the object, string, etc... in your current project, Then gives you a report about it.

Anyway, Since you renamed it already you can write some tests for it. Tests are prefect for your case.

Comment: Eclipse's rename refactoring doesn't handle url template tags. I'll have to see if Visual Studio does.

Comment: @zmbq save yourself some headache and download a trial of PyCharm (instead of Visual Studio). From someone who uses both.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating test cases for your views that at the very least make sure they return a 200 response?  Although this would require more front-end work and obviously wouldn't accomplish exactly what you're looking to do, it would help you identify the views that had these named url errors and allow you to programmatically test your entire site in the future.

Comment: While this will work, it's a lot more work than a simple process that goes through all url tags and tries to `reverse` them. I wondered if something like this exists.